# Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule

Tags: android, image, android-glide

Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

In Gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Comment: Please include all of your code in order to attempt implementing the AppGlideModule.

Comment: People finding this from Google, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901629/glide-showing-error-failed-to-find-generatedappglidemodule

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide showing error: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901629/glide-showing-error-failed-to-find-generatedappglidemodule)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in build.gradle.

It solved my problem!

And if your project is kotlin,try replace "annotationProcessor" to "kapt"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle you can add a dependency on Glide using either Maven Central or JCenter. You will also need to include a dependency on the support library.
check documentation here [docs](http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#gradle)

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this-:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

If you are using android 3.0 then use this-:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue and this did not resolve it.