# Glide showing error: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule

Tags: android, data-binding, android-glide

I am trying to load an image using glide but somehow I can not load the image using glide. As it shows following error:

> Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored.

I have reffered [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48220260/3342570) too. But, I already have the updated verion of glide.

In my gradle, I have added

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

and

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
```

**Code**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.SettingActivity">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="settingsViewModel"
            type="com.sevenbits.android.mvvmsample.viewmodel.SettingsViewModel"/>

    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_bg">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:image_url="@{settingsViewModel.imageUrl}"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

                  ...
            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**CustomBindingAdapter**

```
public class CustomBindingAdapter {

@BindingAdapter({"bind:image_url"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions=requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.boy_32);

        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: please provide your build.gradle file code for app level and project level.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer [here](http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html).

What I have done :

**Step-1**

I created an empty class named `GlideApp`

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class GlideApp extends AppGlideModule {

}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add annotation `@GlideModule`.

**Step-2**
After that, I build/rebuild the project and then, replaced `Glide` with `GlideApp`.and now no need to use `RequestOptions`.

```
public class CustomBindingAdapter {

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:image_url"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {

//        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
//        requestOptions=requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.boy_32);

        GlideApp.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.boy_32)
                .into(imageView);

//            Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
//                    .load(url)
//                    .apply(requestOptions)
//                    .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
For androidx and Glide versin 4.9.0:

**In my app's gradle.build:**

```
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

**In my gradle.properties:**

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

That's all.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Glide version 4.9.0. This causes error "cannot resolve method 'with'

Comment: @ezaspi if you are using Kotlin, you need to replace `annotationProcessor` by `kapt` in your build.gradle dependency. Remember to add `apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"` too. Moreover, you are referencing your `AppGlideModule` implementation but you should use `GlideApp` instead,

Comment: Not working for me With method not found tried all bellow solution.

Answer (score 46):

**Kotlin Solution:**

Make sure you are adding the following in your **gradle file** (replace annotationProcessor with kapt [source](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#kotlin) ):

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Add **AppGlideModule** implementation in your application [GlideSource][2] (You may override the default methods [overrideSource][3]):

```
import android.content.Context
import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.bumptech.glide.signature.ObjectKey

@GlideModule
class AppNameGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder)
        builder.apply { RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) }
    }

}
```

While using glide, use **GlideApp** instead of **Glide**, example:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .into(imageView)
```

Comment: @SpyZip Try rebuilding the app( Build > Rebuild Project) or Invalidate cache ( File > Invalidate Caches / Restart)

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães Please check whether you have created an additional file which extends AppGlideModule

Comment: @Arshak, i try to find in source with android studio tools, and nothing was found the solution to compile the code was rename the class to GlideApps, is that right?

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães No you shouldn’t name the class that extends AppGlideModule to GlideApp, i tried this and i got a compilation error, so instead rename AppNameGlideModule to whatever your apps name is appended by GlideModule(it’s not mandatory, but for understanding purpose), example: CalculatorGlideModule. After that, first build the project so that files can get generated and then run it.

Comment: The "Duplicate Class" error will occur if you name the new class "GlideApp". You should name it something else, for example "MyGlideModule". The class GlideApp will be generated for you.

Comment: @Arshak Your code disables caching(.signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis().toShort()))) I guess. You should try simpler configs for public.

Comment: @SiamakSiaSoft I saw your edit. It should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I have faced this issue with `Glide:4.9.0` with **AndroidX**
solved it like this

In your gradle.properties
`android.useAndroidX = true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`

In your build.gradle
`//Glide dependency
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'`

Then add your `CustomGlideModule`
`@GlideModule
public class CustomeGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}`

The final step generates the GlideModule
**Build** >> **Make Project** and you should see the generated module in your build folder

Comment: What to write inside `CustomeGlideModule` class? If nothing, then is this required.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB override the applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) method.

Answer (score 10):

All above answer is True and work fine

but i noticed when use **#placeholder** and **#error** method the glide work fine with out build **GlideModule** class as mentioned above

Example :
When use glide like this is not work and give must build **GlideModule**

```
Glide.with(this)
             .load(uri)
                .into(imageView);
```

and this is work fine

```
Glide.with(this).load(uri).placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal).error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error).into(imageView);
```

Comment: does not work for me, I am using all placeholder, error, load. which version you are using? i tried with 4.12.0 and 4.8.0

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions (`v4.15.1` and above):

`build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
ksp 'com.github.bumptech.glide:ksp:4.15.1'
```

then create this empty class:

```
@GlideModule
class GlideApp : AppGlideModule()
```

And that's it! **No need to use `GlideApp`**. Just do it as before:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("your url")
.into(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ridhi's Answer:

For me to make it work properly I had to include `isManifestParsingEnabled`.

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class MyGlideApp extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in build.gradle (app)

```
def glide_version = "4.11.0"
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"){
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

in build.gradle (Project)

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
        ....
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        ....
}
```

in your respective Class

> ```
> import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
> import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget
>
> Glide.with(imageView.rootView.context)
> .asBitmap()
> .load("your url")
> .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
>      override fun setResource(resource: Bitmap?) {
>          imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
>          super.setResource(resource)
>      }
> })
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One more reason that this could happen is if you have migrated to KSP. Glide still doesn't support KSP.

Comment: How it's related to "Kerbal Space Program"?

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii very funny. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

### build.gradle

```
api("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"){
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
kapt 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.4.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

### CustomGlideApp

```
package com.example.android.common.modules;

import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class CustomGlideApp extends AppGlideModule { }
```

### Make Project

**Build** > **Make Project**

### Using

Observe that GlideApp (generated) is called and not the CustomGlideApp class.

```
import com.example.android.common.modules.GlideApp;

GlideApp.with()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to face this type of issue like **`Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored.`**

I have fixed my issue after lots of time.

I made mistake in the **XML** file I had set the wrong **height width** of UIImageView that's why glide throw an error.

Please check `UIImageView` Height-Width Properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have follow all the instruction that was tell above and not working at all. the mistake i made was set the height and width in imageview that i made to match_parent and that's why my image wouldn't appear. the correct is you cant set that all to match_parent, one of them must used wrap_content atribute.