# Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule

Tags: android, image, android-glide

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
```

```
String valueImage;
Glide.with(this)
     .load(Uri.parse(valueImage))
     .into(imageView);
```

```
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

----
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide showing error: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901629/glide-showing-error-failed-to-find-generatedappglidemodule)

Comment: That didn't help me!

Comment: [The official intercom android sample app](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android) has the same warning, so I assume it cannot be that bad (?). See also [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1880) that it is apparently okay to ignore this warning if you do not use the generated API and libraries that use LibraryGlideModules