# Glide can't download image to ImageView

Tags: android, image, download, android-glide

I am switch from iOS to Android and try to download the image by URL, for this problem I find that a lot of developers prefer to use the Glide library, I am trying to download images but can't understand why I see the error image. Look please on my code and say what I am doing wrong?

This error happens with JPEG and PNG formats.
Glide version 4.12.0

Code:

```
val urlJpg = "http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/images/android_cat.jpg"
lateinit var img: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

img = findViewById(R.id.imageView)

Glide.with(this) //1
    .load(urlJpg)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    .into(img)
}
```

Log:

```
2021-04-01 11:49:04.750 18374-18374/? I/glideandpicass: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-04-01 11:49:04.828 18374-18374/? I/glideandpicass: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-04-01 11:49:04.832 18374-18374/? W/glideandpicass: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-04-01 11:49:05.517 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-04-01 11:49:05.519 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-04-01 11:49:05.593 18374-18404/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2021-04-01 11:49:05.607 18374-18404/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2021-04-01 11:49:05.626 18374-18404/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2021-04-01 11:49:05.984 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/glideandpicass: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-01 11:49:05.986 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/glideandpicass: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-01 11:49:06.119 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
2021-04-01 11:49:06.390 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/glideandpicass: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-01 11:49:06.390 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/glideandpicass: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-01 11:49:06.390 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/glideandpicass: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2021-04-01 11:49:06.468 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/Glide: Load failed for http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/images/android_cat.jpg with size [1173x746]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
2021-04-01 11:49:06.471 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:98)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:280)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to developer.alexanderklimov.ru not permitted
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:93)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:280) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393) 
2021-04-01 11:49:06.514 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8eece00, tid 18402
2021-04-01 11:49:06.532 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2021-04-01 11:49:06.582 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-04-01 11:49:06.585 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe8eedc70: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2021-04-01 11:49:06.594 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8eedc70: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe923a070) (first time)
2021-04-01 11:49:06.618 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2021-04-01 11:49:06.619 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2021-04-01 11:49:06.620 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8eed570, tid 18402
2021-04-01 11:49:06.621 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2021-04-01 11:49:06.621 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f7ef4000 size 0x2000
2021-04-01 11:49:06.639 18374-18402/com.example.testglideandpicasso D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
```

Glide logs:

```
2021-04-01 11:49:06.119 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
2021-04-01 11:49:06.468 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso W/Glide: Load failed for http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/images/android_cat.jpg with size [1173x746]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
2021-04-01 11:49:06.471 18374-18374/com.example.testglideandpicasso I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:98)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:280)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to developer.alexanderklimov.ru not permitted
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:93)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:280) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

Comment: Can you share your logs for glide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding Network Security Config xml file in manifest**

res/xml/network_security_config.xml:

- Create the Network security config.xml in resource xml folder.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <network-security-config>
>     <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
>         <domain includeSubdomains="true">developer.alexanderklimov.ru/</domain>
>     </domain-config>
> </network-security-config>
> ```

- Add the Network security config.xml in manifest like following.

> ```
> <application
>     android:name=".MyApplication"
>     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing **INTERNET** permission in your AndroidManifest.xml.
Please define permission before application element in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any internet request on Android platform must have this permission, for more permissions, please check android developer documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en

Have a nice trip on your Android development!

Comment: Sorry, but the problem at another place :(

Answer (score 0):

I examined the log and try solved my problem using this post [Glide showing error: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901629/glide-showing-error-failed-to-find-generatedappglidemodule)

The example above will be good for some situation, but for my problem solution simple need to add allow clear HTTP traffic inside Manifest file.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

All my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testglideandpicasso">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestGlideAndPicasso">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```