# trying to load mp3 song artist image it's getting Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed error

Tags: java, android, image, audio-player

I am trying to load artist image from mp3 song. some file loaded successfully but some files not loaded.

**here is my code:**

```
public void metaData(Uri uri){
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString());
        int durationTotal = Integer.parseInt(songsList.get(position).getDuration()) / 1000;
        tv_end.setText(formattime(durationTotal));
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if(art != null){
            Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(art)..into(img_minSongImage);
        }else{
            Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(R.drawable.profile).into(img_minSongImage);
        }

    }
```

logcat image:

[image]

Comment: This thread may be some helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901629/glide-showing-error-failed-to-find-generatedappglidemodule

Comment: Also, replace the image with the log extract as text (and use code formatting), as the image isn't readable, and more importantly; not indexable. 

Comment: no it's not working